# KeyEvent characters

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keylistener, keyevent

I have a question about a `KeyListener`.
When I get the `KeyEvent` and do a `getKeyChar()`  I'm tyring to compare to and `*` asterisk and I was going to use one of the `KeyEvent.VK_` defines which works for a lot of the keys.

But for this particular key and some others the values don't match up.

The `* getKeyChar()` will return `0x2a` and the `getKeyCode()` returns `0x38`.  The define for `0x38` is `VK_8` not `VK_ASTERISK` which is `0x97`.

Why do certain keycodes match up and not others. Most do thouh. If I just do a character compare that works`( == '*')`, but I'm not sure if this the best solution?

Thank you for all help!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, you're misunderstanding something.

Keys are keys, and symbols are symbols. Symbols are results of key presses, and the same key can result in different symbols depending on circumstances (key combinations like <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> etc).

So, `VK_8` **key** code stands for the **key** that can produce symbols `8`, `*` and possibly others depending on keyboard localization.

And the <kbd>*</kbd> dedicated **key** on numeric keyboard is `VK_MULTIPLY` - it can produce just one symbol `*` (to my knowledge).

You probably shouldn't care about the **key** that the user pressed, but about the **symbol** that this user action produced.

This info you can get with `getKeyChar()`, but please note that if the user presses <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> combination to produce `*` it's actually two keys (<kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>8</kbd>) and you will get two events, and the first one (for <kbd>Shift</kbd>) will produce an unreadable symbol.

Comment: That last suggestion seemed to be working for me. I get a 0xFFFF which is an CHAR_UNDEFIEND for the shift which I just ignore and then I do a getKeyChar() the next time I'm donig a getKeyChar() == '*' and that seems to work.Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

depends of [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

if you want to determine from [JTextComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) then use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html), if you want to modify Char sequence then use [DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430683/714968)

otherwise look at [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), because [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) is designated for `AWT Components`

Comment: It just a JTextField I'm using. Is there anything wrong with leaving it as  getKetChar() =='*' ? Will not that always work?

Comment: for a JTextField use only DocumentListener/DocumentFilter, there isn't another correct way

Answer (score 2):

1. `KeyEvent.VK_ASTERISK` is a constant reserved for the (virtual) keyboard key that has * marked on it. It does not have to match the character that is produced when someone pushes the key.

   If you want to use the VK constants you have to listen for key up and key down events and use the `KeyEvent.getKeyCode()` method. If you want to use characters you have listen for key typed events and use the `KeyEvent.getKeyChar()` method.

   Some key codes may match the character just because it's easier to define it that way; there is no real need to do it that way.
2. You say that you got a VK_8 from `getKeyCode` for typing the asterisk. Did you push an actual asterisk key or did you have to type Shift-8?

Comment: when I'm pressing the `*` on numeric keyboard I'm getting `VK_MULTIPLY` and not `VK_ASTERISK`