# Adding textfield validation to multiple textfields 

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield, inputverifier

I'm trying to add validation to 4 JTextFields using only numeric characters (0-9). The code I have for one JTextField is:

```
txtf_xCoord.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent)
        {
            if (txtf_xCoord.getText().length() < 3 && keyEvent.getKeyChar() >= '0' && keyEvent.getKeyChar() <= '9')
            {
                // Optional
                super.keyTyped(keyEvent);
            }
            else
            {
                // Discard the event
                keyEvent.consume();
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there a more efficient way of adding this validation to the rest of the JTextFields without copy and pasting the code for each?

Comment: make a class that extends from JTextField and in it add your listener.
and everywhere of your program create of that class.

Comment: @medhi - wrong ... you _never_ use a KeyListener in Swing, especially not for validating text input

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html), take a look at the following code :

```
public class NumericVerifier extends InputVerifier {
        @Override   
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            //Check type of the control
                String text = "";

if(input instanceof JTextField) {   
                JTextField tf = (JTextField) input; 
                text = tf.getText().trim(); 
            }

        boolean matches = text.matches("^\\d+$");
        input.setBackground( ( matches ) ? Color.WHITE :  Color.RED);
        return matches; 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- easiest and most safiest way would be to add one instance of [DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430683/714968) to the [JTextFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)
- never use [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for Swing JComponent, use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead
- for listening in the [JTextComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)s is there [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can convert your anonymous class to a real class and then instantiate that class everywhere. Now, you could also take a look at `JFormattedTextField`