# Clarification on modifying a Document's contents from a DocumentListener

Tags: java, swing

From the Swing tutorial on [text components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter):

> You may want to change the document's text within a document listener. However, you should never modify the contents of a text component from within a document listener. If you do, the program will likely deadlock. Instead, you can use a formatted text field or provide a document filter.

I am confused. So what is the correct way to change the text eg. as a result of a KeyEvent ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) using `DocumentListener` for

- output from `JTextComponent` to the GUI
- `HightLighter` or `Styled text`

2) `DocumentFilter` for filtering of

- unwanted chars,
- chars sequence(s),

these filtered chars could be

- replaced with another char (or with defined chars sequence)
- removed (never will be displayed in the `JTextComponent`)

3) similair funcionality to provide `JFormattedTextField`is possible to input to the `JTextComponent` only chars `0 - 9`, `decimal separator`, `negative sing`,

4) 
    So what is the correct way to change the text eg. as a result of a KeyEvent ?

use [DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430683/714968)

Answer (score 3):

A direct answer is using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` placing the `Document` modification code there. But mKorbel's answer (+1) covers most of the cases you can imagine.

Comment: @StanislavL Thanks. It was exactly the concurrency issue I worried about and didn't find completely clear from the description in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The text say's that you may want to use a document listener. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) is a example how to write one.

> A Swing text component uses a Document to represent its content.
>   Document events occur when the content of a document changes in any
>   way.

So, always that your text component changes the document listener will fire, but the text says that you cannot change the value of the component in this listener.

In a `KeyListener` (that's not a document listener) you can change the value using `setText()`.

Depending on what you want, i suggest you look [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html).