# JTextArea Document Listener updating text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, insert-update, documentlistener

I have a JTextArea and I'd like to listen when the user pastes text in the JtextArea. Specifically, I'd like to do the following:

Get the text they pasted, remove whitespaces, and replace the JTextArea text with the edited text without spaces (rather than the original text the user pasted).

How can I do this using a DocumentListener, and avoiding `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.`, which comes as a result of the following code:

```
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {

        final String replace = jTextArea1.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            jTextArea1.setText(replace);
            }
         });

    }
```

Comment: What's the stack trace from that exception?  This seems like it should work.  Unless there's some prohibition of re-setting the text from within the event handler, in which case you could try a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` call.

Comment: I tried SwingUtilities.invokeLater (see updated question). The error is still thrown.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?  It's not clear (to me) what's causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't any issue with method `insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent)`, sure JTextArea can accepting only chars input, if you'll have an issue use JEditorPane, there you can importing another Java AWT and Swing Objects too

code example

```
private DocumentListener docListener = new DocumentListener() {

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        printIt(documentEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        printIt(documentEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        printIt(documentEvent);
    }

    private void printIt(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        DocumentEvent.EventType type = documentEvent.getType();
        //your code
    }
};
```

for replacing inserted characters you have to add [DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429459/get-a-key-from-jtextarea/9430683#9430683)

Comment: However if you try to say textArea.setText(textArea.getText().replaceAll("\\s","")) you get the area I put in the question

Comment: so I just need to call another function to do it, rather than put the setText() inside the changeUpdate function?

Comment: [here you can see basic rules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9692926/714968), and then you can combine both Listeners (sure by leaving insertUpdate in DocumentListener empty)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like remove white character use `\S or \s` in regexp. If you woudlike to remove only space you may do it in this same way. Read more about regexp: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: I already am removing the whitespace. Please read the question, for it is not the problem.