# Making a String accept only letters ( no numbers ).

Tags: java, string, swing, netbeans-7, jtextfield

Is it possible to allow only letters or numbers in a string in java ? for example :

```
String Text;
Text = jTextField1.getText();
```

now

```
if (Text is a number) {System.out.println("Invalid Input");}
```

Comment: Hint: Stick to common naming conventions and make fields and variables lowercase (i.e. `Text` in your case).

Comment: Please have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477354/how-to-allow-introducing-only-digits-in-jtextfield/9478124#9478124), also, simply replace `if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(len - 1)))` with `if (!Character.isDigit(text.charAt(len - 1)))` and I guess it will work  for your scenario as well :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have two choices to use

- [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) with proper `Formatter` or `InputVerifier`
- use [DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430683/714968)

---

- notice don't use `String Text;` (possible reserved word for API name or its method) use `String text;` more in the [Naming convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 1):

Addition: You could do it also like the following, though i recommend mKorbel's answer.

```
try  {
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Text) + "is a valid input.");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("The input "+ Text + "is invalid");
}
```