# JTextPane got Next Value before keyReleased method ends

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jtextpane, documentfilter

I have a JTextPane which is bind with KeyReleased Event. My Goal is that whatever
user typed in that TextPane It will print some character.

```
{'I', 'N', 'V', 'A', 'L', 'I', 'D'};
```

Above character printed every keyReleased Event. If the user pressed `any character` then JTextPane Shows `'I'` after next event shows 'N' like wise.

If I pressed one by one its working properly. But my problem is that If I typed rapidly I got the typed character.

How can I hide these characters?

**KeyPressedEvent Code:**

`fooString` is char array with 13 char.

```
count++; //count of event
if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
{
  int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Do you want to exit");
  if(option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
  {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
else if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
{
  if(this.txtPane.getText().length() != 0)
  count--;
}
else
{
  /*Get the value and show fooString value */
  try {
    String val = this.txtPane.getText();
    int rem = count % fooString.length;
    //System.out.println(val.substring(0, val.length()-1));
    txtPane.setText(val.substring(count-1, val.length()-1));
    if(rem == 0)
    rem = foolString.length;
    if(count % 26 == 0)
    {
      txtPane.setText(val.substring(0, val.length()-1) 
          + fooString[rem-1] +"\n");
      lineCount++;
      count = 0;
    }
    else
    txtPane.setText(val.substring(0, val.length()-1) + fooString[rem-1]);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(A.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
```

Cheers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- don't to use [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)
- use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

> My Goal is that whatever user typed in that TextPane It will print
>   some character.

- use [DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430683/714968) and/or (for `{'I', 'N', 'V', 'A', 'L', 'I', 'D;}`) with `Pattern`

Comment: Ya. This is what i need for my solution. Will Try this.