# How to set Scrollable TextArea in Java for group Layout?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea, keylistener

I have a problem. Every time, when I add more Symbols(Numbers) to TextArea, it doesn't make it scrollable.  EDIT: now it works as I want. I only needed to change 2 words. Thanks.

```
class NumOnly extends KeyAdapter {  

    private String Atlauts = "[^0-9]";  //Allowed Buttons.
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   //Key event. What happens when the button is pressed
        String curText = ((JTextComponent) e.getSource()).getText();  //Current text
        curText = curText.replaceAll(Atlauts, ""); 

        ((JTextComponent) e.getSource()).setText(curText);  
    }  
}  

public class kursadarbs{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame= new JFrame();
        JPanel panel= new JPanel();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //components
        JLabel label1= new JLabel("Insert first number: ");

        final JTextField textbox1= new JTextField(10);
        textbox1.addKeyListener(new NumOnly());

        JLabel label2= new JLabel("Insert second number: ");

        final JTextField textbox2= new JTextField(10);
        textbox2.addKeyListener(new NumOnly());

        JButton button= new JButton("Calculate");

        final JTextArea textarea= new JTextArea(20,20); //Result is stored in there
        textarea.setEditable(false);
        textarea.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane scroll= new JScrollPane(textarea);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textarea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textarea.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Result"));




        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(groupLayout);  
        groupLayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);      
        groupLayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true); 

        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup HorSGroup= groupLayout.createSequentialGroup(); 
        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup VerSGroup= groupLayout.createSequentialGroup(); 

        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup HParallelGroup1= groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup HParallelGroup2= groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup HParallelGroup3= groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);

        HParallelGroup1.addComponent(label1); //adding components to the group
        HParallelGroup1.addComponent(label2);
        HParallelGroup2.addComponent(textbox1);
        HParallelGroup2.addComponent(textbox2);
        HParallelGroup2.addComponent(scroll);
        HParallelGroup3.addComponent(button);

        HorSGroup.addGroup(HParallelGroup1);
        HorSGroup.addGroup(HParallelGroup2);
        HorSGroup.addGroup(HParallelGroup3);

        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup VerPGroup1= groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE); //Vertical group
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup VerPGroup2= groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE);
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup VerPGroup3= groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE);

        VerPGroup1.addComponent(label1); //adding components to groups
        VerPGroup1.addComponent(textbox1);
        VerPGroup1.addComponent(button);
        VerPGroup2.addComponent(label2);
        VerPGroup2.addComponent(textbox2);
        VerPGroup3.addComponent(scroll);

        VerSGroup.addGroup(VerPGroup1);
        VerSGroup.addGroup(VerPGroup2);
        VerSGroup.addGroup(VerPGroup3);

        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(HorSGroup);
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(VerSGroup);




        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (int) (dimension.getWidth()/4);
        int y = (int) (dimension.getHeight()/4);
        frame.setLocation(x, y); //Places the program almost in the middle

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
               //what happens when "calculate" is pressed.
                String first = null, second = null; 
                int first1=0, second1=0;

               first= textbox1.getText();  //getting textbox1 value.
               second= textbox2.getText();

               if(!first.isEmpty() && !second.isEmpty()) //If fields are not empty..
               {
                   first1= Integer.parseInt(first);  //string to integer.
                   second1= Integer.parseInt(second);

                   if(first1<second1){ //Check, if the first number is bigger than second.
                   System.out.println(first1);                 
                   textarea.append(first+"\n");
                   }// Ja ir pareizi 
                   else 
                   {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect data. " );
                   }
               } else 
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect data." );
               }
            }
        });


        frame.add(panel); //add the panel
        frame.setSize(500, 500); //program size in pix
        frame.setResizable(false); //putting that the frame can't change size
        frame.setTitle("Kursa darbs");
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Well, The main problem is the Textarea. As you can see, English is not my native language and I'm a beginner for JFrame.
I have tried everything... Please help.

Thank you Already.

Comment: Unfortunately, since I don't speak Latvian(?) I am not able to understand what that GUI is supposed to do or how it is supposed to work.  Please run the comments, attribute and class names, the button text, & labels through Google translate.

Comment: I fixed the comments, but they don't give a lot of new info. The main idea of the programm... Well, I'm making a program which searches prime numbers between 2 inserted numbers (which are inserted in textbox1 and textbox2). I know how to find prime numbers, but I don't know how to make the frame. Kind of stupid, but well... I'm a student, and I like to learn something new. Really this even isn't obligatory for me, but I want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the `JTextArea` to the groups, *add the `JScrollPane` that contains it*!

```
    //HParallelGroup2.addComponent(textarea);
    HParallelGroup2.addComponent(scroll);
    HParallelGroup3.addComponent(button);

    HorSGroup.addGroup(HParallelGroup1); //Horizontālās grupas tiek pievienotas sakārtotajai grupai
    HorSGroup.addGroup(HParallelGroup2);
    HorSGroup.addGroup(HParallelGroup3);

    GroupLayout.ParallelGroup VerPGroup1= groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE); //Izveido Vertikālās grupas.
    GroupLayout.ParallelGroup VerPGroup2= groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE);
    GroupLayout.ParallelGroup VerPGroup3= groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE);

    VerPGroup1.addComponent(label1); //Pievieno objektus
    VerPGroup1.addComponent(textbox1);
    VerPGroup1.addComponent(button);
    VerPGroup2.addComponent(label2);
    VerPGroup2.addComponent(textbox2);
    //VerPGroup3.addComponent(textarea);
    VerPGroup3.addComponent(scroll);
```

Comment: Thank you allot, It worked as a charm :) Now I got to learn more about Java.

Answer (score 3):

- never ever to use [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)
- use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) instead (allowed to insert `String`, `Copy-Paste`, `SystemClipBoard`, e.i.)
- for filtering of unwanted `char(s)` to use [DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430683/714968)
- use [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) with `Number formatter` instead of parsing number from [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) or add `DocumentFilter` with `Pattern` to `JTextField` for filtering only numbers